# Use Stata to generate new variable, based on combination types of variables

Tags: stata

Say I have a dataset with three variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and having 5 observations. Like the following:

```
    a   b   c
    1   0   1
    1   1   1
    0   1   0
    0   1   1
    1   0   0
```

Now I want to generate a new variable called `type`, which is a possible combination of variable `a`, `b` and `c`. Specifically,

- `type=1` if `a=b=c=0`
- `type=2` if `a=c=0 & b=1`
- `type=3` if `a=b=0 & c=1`
- `type=4` if `a=0 & b=c=1`
- `type=5` if `a=1 & b=c=0`
- `type=6` if `a=b=1 & c=0`
- `type=7` if `a=c=1 & b=0`
- `type=8` if `a=b=c=1`

The new dataset I want to get is:

```
    a   b   c   type
    1   0   1   7
    1   1   1   8
    0   1   0   2
    0   1   1   4
    1   0   0   5
```

Are there any general ways to realize this in Stata? It's better if this can also be extended when `type` is large, say 100 types. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the specific values of `type` don't matter, `egen`'s `group` function works.

*E.g.*:

```
clear 
input   a   b   c
    1   0   1
    1   1   1
    0   1   0
    0   1   1
    1   0   0
    0   1   0
    1   1   1
end

sort a b c // not necessary, but clearer presentation
egen type = group(a b c)

li
```

with the result

```
     +------------------+
     | a   b   c   type |
     |------------------|
  1. | 0   1   0      1 |
  2. | 0   1   0      1 |
  3. | 0   1   1      2 |
  4. | 1   0   0      3 |
  5. | 1   0   1      4 |
     |------------------|
  6. | 1   1   1      5 |
  7. | 1   1   1      5 |
     +------------------+
```

Comment: Good, and even better if you add the -label- option.